# in Pandas how to reference 2 dataframes and replace the column

Tags: python, pandas

There are 2 dataframes:
need to use 'Place' ref table to replace (or add a column to indicate) 'Region' in df by 'Code' in ref.
Mind, this is a sample, in real file, there are 100,000+ roles, and more complicated values. Please help

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1/1/11','1/2/11','1/2/11','1/2/11','1/3/11','1/3/11','1/3/11','1/3/11','1/4/11','1/5/11','1/5/11','1/5/11'],\
'Prod': ['Quad','Bellen','Quad','Bellen','Sunshine','Carlota','Sunset','Sunshine','Sunset','Sunset','Sunshine','Carlota'], \
'Region': ['East','South','West','West','East','MidWest','South','South','MidWest','South','West','West']})

ref=pd.DataFrame({'Place': ['West','East','South','MidWest'],\
'Code':['W','E','S','MW']})
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer what you're asking?

Comment: hi, Im completely new to this site. I'll edit right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need map

```
df['Region'] = df['Region'].map(ref.set_index('Place')['Code'])


    Date    Prod        Region
0   1/1/11  Quad        E
1   1/2/11  Bellen      S
2   1/2/11  Quad        W
3   1/2/11  Bellen      W
4   1/3/11  Sunshine    E
5   1/3/11  Carlota     MW
6   1/3/11  Sunset      S
7   1/3/11  Sunshine    S
8   1/4/11  Sunset      MW
9   1/5/11  Sunset      S
10  1/5/11  Sunshine    W
11  1/5/11  Carlota     W
```

Edit: If you want to retain the name of the region that is not present in ref, use

```
df['Region'] = df['Region'].map(ref.set_index('Place')['Code']).combine_first(df['Region'])
```

Edit: @Wen is right, you can use replace instead of map

```
df['Region'].replace(ref.set_index('Place')['Code'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. can I add, if one of value in 'Region' doesn't have reference in ref table (eg. North). What can I do to replace all referenceable value, AND retain 'North' as a valid value in 'Region'? Thanks again

Comment: @S.Gu maybe you can try replace then .

Comment: Yes, definitely :D